# Template class instantiation in default parameter not allowed in MSVC12?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, compiler-errors, default-parameters

I just extracted the following problem in our project. The following code just compiles fine with g++

```
#include <vector>

class A {};

typedef std::vector<A*> vec_t;

class bar {
public:
  bar(vec_t) {};
};

class foo
{
public:
  foo(bar* a = new bar(vec_t())) {};
};

class B
{};

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

However, the Visual Studio Compiler (VC12, but I presume all others too) doesn't understand that in the default argument for the c'tor of *foo* the c'tor of *bar* is called which takes an instance of a vector as an argument. This causes an error for every class/struct declared after this expression:

```
error C2462: 'B' : cannot define a type in a 'new-expression'
```

I don't want to discuss the software design of the c'tor, but is this a compiler issue or just not allowed in standard C++ and the g++ just not being strict about that?

First, I thought that a template-instantiation in a default parameter may be not allowed or nested c'tors in a default argument. However, if I use another c'tor of the vector:

```
foo(bar* a = new bar(vec_t(0))) {}
```

it compiles with MSVC. I just can't see why the upper version shouldn't compile? Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Try `new bar((vect_t())) {}`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is an issue with the "most vexing parse" (see the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) article on it for more info).  One way to disambiguate the new expression is to add parentheses around the constructor like this

```
foo(bar* a = new bar((vec_t()))) {};
```

When it comes to standards compliance I'm not sure.  I skimmed section 6.8 (Ambiguity Resolution) and 5.3.4 (New) of [N3690](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf) and without thinking about it too hard nothing stood out either way.  Maybe a real language lawyer will need to step in to give an answer.